# Groovy Grails Tool Suite Requries Java Runtime Environment 1.6.0

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite

I just downloaded the Spring Groovy/Grails tool suite version 3.5.1 and the installer fails with the note "This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.6.0". Obviously, I will be installing 1.6 and overriding my path to get the installer to work, but my question is why does the Groovy/Grails tool suite installer require 1.6 and can't install with 1.7?

Comment: You need at least 1.6, but it works with JDK 1.7 (I don't have 1.6 on my laptop, and I installed GGTS without a problem).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I continually got the error on install (I'm on Windows 8.1 if that matters). I was able to get around it by installing 1.6 and overriding my environment variables. It works fine on 1.7, just doesn't install with 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GGTS itself doesn't require a JDK6 to run, it can run with JDK6, JDK7 or JDK8. But if you are on a Mac, the installer application can run with JDK6 only (due to some limitations with the underlying native JVM launcher application from Apple that runs with JDK6 only). You can/should download the tar.gz version of GGTS instead, just extract that, and run it. That will work without installing JDK6 before.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue I faced is not with running it, but with the initial installation.

Comment: Understand. As I said, the installer requires a JDK6 at the moment. If you want to avoid that, you can use the tar.gz version of GGTS for the installation. It doesn't contain the installer app, but GGTS itself. Just extract that archive and go.